# using method tickSeconds in Class Clock on Java

Tags: java, java-8, clock

I am making a Swing application for a clock.

I was trying to find the current time, and ended up using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but I am still curious as to how to fix this. I get a lot of errors similar to this, so I would like to know how to fix this.

Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#system-java.time.ZoneId-

First, I tried

```
Clock second;
second = Clock.tickSeconds(Clock.getZone());
```

but I get an error `non-static method getZone() cannot be referenced from a static context`

So I tried

```
Clock second;
second = Clock.tickSeconds(new Clock.getZone());
```

but I get this:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   class getZone
location: class Clock
```

So how can I edit the code to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getZone()` is an instance method, so you need to get an instance of `Clock` first:

```
second = Clock.tickSeconds(Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone());
```

`new Clock.getZone()` will not work because

1. Constructors are called with parenthesis
2. `Clock` is abstract an abstract class, so it cannot be instantiated directly.

Comment: Thanks! But how is one supposed to figure out that systemDefaultZone() is needed to instantiate getZone() instead of other methods?

Comment: If you look at the documentation, there are a couple of methods for obtaining an instance.